# SRTP Issue : PJSIP Error initializing media channel: Not Acceptable Here [status=170488]

Tags: ios, ssl, asterisk, rtp, pjsip

I'm trying to get SRTP going in my iOS application using PJSIP. I have TLS working and without SRTP I can make and receive calls. However with SRTP I'm getting this odd 488 error on the INVITE. It's not able to initialize the media.

I've read other articles mentioning about the codecs. But I've insured that the codes being used by my Asterisk server and those compiled with PJSIP library on my iOS app are the same. The only thing I'm seeing here is that I'm enabled the crypto and PJSIP isn't liking it. Any thoughts?

```
INVITE sip:[REDACTED]@[REDACTED]:47229;transport=TLS;ob SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/TLS [REDACTED]:5161;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPj8ea1a332-0748-438f-ae74-5d17b038891d;alias

From: "Test" <sip:asterisk@172.31.18.138>;tag=7c3663cb-b5f5-4762-8526-8425d18b2466

To: <sip:[REDACTED]@[REDACTED];ob>

Contact: <sip:asterisk@[REDACTED]:5161;transport=TLS>

Call-ID: f454ef36-01ea-4f29-9482-4a10768bf1b7

CSeq: 24942 INVITE

Allow: OPTIONS, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, PRACK, REGISTER, MESSAGE, REFER

Supported: 100rel, timer, replaces, norefersub, path

Session-Expires: 1800

Min-SE: 90

Max-Forwards: 70

User-Agent: FPBX-AsteriskNOW-13.0.190.12(13.13.1)

Content-Type: application/sdp

Content-Length:   398



v=0

o=- 1582453973 1582453973 IN IP4 172.31.18.138

s=Asterisk

c=IN IP4 [REDACTED]

t=0 0

m=audio 11410 RTP/AVP 3 110 9 97 101

a=crypto:1 AES_CM_128_HMAC_SHA1_80 inline:84m7hqGvMjTU21xzkhBS3RQpQQjJ+aep0VwSlhx+

a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000

a=rtpmap:110 speex/8000

a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000

a=rtpmap:97 iLBC/8000

a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000

a=fmtp:101 0-16

a=ptime:20

a=maxptime:60

a=sendrecv


--end msg--
19:10:11.601   pjsua_call.c  .Incoming Request msg INVITE/cseq=24942 (rdata0x1421f0540)
19:10:11.603 tsx0x1421fe0a8  ...Transaction created for Request msg INVITE/cseq=24942 (rdata0x1421f0540)
19:10:11.603 tsx0x1421fe0a8  ..Incoming Request msg INVITE/cseq=24942 (rdata0x1421f0540) in state Null
19:10:11.603 tsx0x1421fe0a8  ...State changed from Null to Trying, event=RX_MSG
19:10:11.603 dlg0x1421fd8a8  ....Transaction tsx0x1421fe0a8 state changed to Trying
19:10:11.603 dlg0x1421fd8a8  ..UAS dialog created
19:10:11.603 dlg0x1421fd8a8  ..Module mod-invite added as dialog usage, data=0x141de7588
19:10:11.603 dlg0x1421fd8a8  ...Session count inc to 3 by mod-invite
19:10:11.603 inv0x1421fd8a8  ..UAS invite session created for dialog dlg0x1421fd8a8
19:10:11.603 dlg0x1421fd8a8  ...Session count inc to 3 by mod-pjsua
19:10:11.603  pjsua_media.c  ..Call 0: initializing media..
19:10:11.603   pjsua_call.c  ..Error initializing media channel: Not Acceptable Here [status=170488]
19:10:11.604       endpoint  ..Response msg 488/INVITE/cseq=24942 (tdta0x1421fe800) created
19:10:11.604 dlg0x1421fd8a8  ...Sending Response msg 488/INVITE/cseq=24942 (tdta0x1421fe800)
19:10:11.606 tsx0x1421fe0a8  ...Sending Response msg 488/INVITE/cseq=24942 (tdta0x1421fe800) in state Trying
19:10:11.606   pjsua_core.c  ....TX 429 bytes Response msg 488/INVITE/cseq=24942 (tdta0x1421fe800) to TLS [REDACTED]:5161:
SIP/2.0 488 Not Acceptable Here

Via: SIP/2.0/TLS [REDACTED]:5161;rport=5161;received=[REDACTED];branch=z9hG4bKPj8ea1a332-0748-438f-ae74-5d17b038891d;alias

Call-ID: f454ef36-01ea-4f29-9482-4a10768bf1b7

From: "Test" <sip:asterisk@172.31.18.138>;tag=7c3663cb-b5f5-4762-8526-8425d18b2466

To: <sip:[REDACTED]@[REDACTED];ob>;tag=5oFGceZO4ZaKpLFEg7piOrM7IV2yeDLT

CSeq: 24942 INVITE

Content-Length:  0




--end msg--
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else has this issue. I'll tell you what solved this for me.

On Asterisk in my endpoint (pjsip show endpoint myendpoint) setting I had **media_encryption_optimistic** set to true. When I set this to **false** everything started working.

I'm not sure why as the how to on asterisk stated to turn this on. But I confirmed at all traffic was indeed encrypted by using wireshark to check the actual voice data.

If anyone know why this would be the case that this needed to be set to false it would help me better understand this. But for now I'm up and running.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error on PJSIP ios and I solved on my end after DISABLING "SRTP" or "S-RTP" or "Secure RTP" or "Secure Transport". I removed this for TLS configuration.

```
    //acc_cfg.srtp_secure_signaling = 1;
    //acc_cfg.use_srtp = PJMEDIA_SRTP_MANDATORY;
```

Answer (score 0):

**488 / Not Acceptable Here**

> I also get the same problem with my server, atlast i find the solution
>   by getting to know that it is because codec, use right codec or
>   disable codec works great for you.